# Imgur secure connection failing

Tags: support, security, imgur

I was reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854631/typescript-foreach-is-not-a-function) on Stack Overflow, it has two links to **https://i.stack.imgur.com**. I'm pretty sure these are images added to the question with the image tool (powered by Imgur) so I clicked the first link and received a security warning.

### Environment

- work-managed laptop, macOS 10.15.7
- home network*
- similar failures in Firefox, Safari, Chrome

### Error

- Firefox 84.0, network tab: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
- Chrome Canary 90.0.4395.0: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

### Certificate issuer

Cisco Umbrella Secondary SubCA sea-SG

[image: a screenshot of potential security risk error from imgur]

Are there other reports of this, is it just my browser? Is Imgur's certificate issuer (Cisco OpenDNS) an issue?

Comment: under firefox 84.0.2 Windows 10 it is normal. any addons? also try another webbrowser to check

Comment: Similar errors in Safari, Firefox, Chrome Canary (MacOS). I'm on a work computer but browsing on our home network, no VPN.

Comment: i think the certificat epool is corrupted on your system, or so configured

Comment: @nbk I think you nudged me in the right direction. I edited my question, but let me know  if this is supposed to be an answer instead.

Comment: If this definitely resolved your issue, then yeah, I'd post it as an answer. It may help others in the future who are using similar types of access-control filtering solutions. (If you're still looking for more help, then I would hold off on posting an answer. But also clarify what additional help you're looking for.)

Answer (score 6):

nbk's questions prompted me to check other environments. I viewed this question on my phone and it loaded the screenshot preview. Noticing my phone was off wireless and using cellular data, I turned on wireless and opened a private browsing window and bingo, broken. **I think the problem was a DNS intercept setup on our home wireless.** Oh the joys of remote learning and filtering your kid's internet activity.

### Quick recap of troubleshooting steps

In case you run into something similar, here are the troubleshooting steps nbk and I walked through to isolate what was happening:

- check another browser
- check browser's security settings
- check extensions and add-ons, disable as needed
- check network: work vpn, wifi vs. cellular data on a phone